# Android app: material design icon

Tags: feature-request, design, android-app

I've noticed that in the Alpha version of the Android App, the icon has not been updated yet to the Material design guidelines.

So I've taken the initiative and I created it for my own:
[image]

The one of the left uses colours from the material colour palette; the one on the right, the original colours.

In my humble opinion, for the sake of keeping the branding, the original colours work better; and do not look out of place in the material guidelines, which is important as well.

If you like it I can provide the needed sizes for the app.

Comment: I don't like how the two middle colours look more similar than the bottom two colours... That may make it look more like the original...

Comment: @Tim I agree, it's the bad thing about the material-coloured version. The original colours are good as they are :)

Comment: They look identical.